# receive push notification and store it without open the notification Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a third party library which provides me push notification service.However I am getting notification but I want to catch it and store it in the application without letting user open the notification.

for instance; notification sent and user received it. but before user press on notification to open it, I want to get the body of the notification and store it in somewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use Broadcast receiver and get it's data inside overridden method onRecieve() of broadcast receiver. After that you can either store data in shared preferences or sqlite database.

Comment: the problem is that if I use Broadcast Receiver, I wont be able to catch the notification since the third party library I am using for firing the notification is using custom Broadcast Receiver in their library. SO however, If I use another Broadcast REceiver in my application, do you think it will work?

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: I am using mgage library. they are firing the notification. even I do their configration in the Manifest

Comment: so when I receive a notification, I can see it and open it but I dont know how to capture it in the application since I am defining their receiver in the manifest

Comment: you can make your own custom broadcast receiver and check what data is received in intent.